# How to realign sections of a x64 portable executable based on section alignment field

Tags: linker, 64-bit, portable-executable, sections

I have been searching high and low for an easy way to manually align any x64 PE to 0x10000 section alignment and all i could find was pe file aligment or realignment.
As a test case i used the source code of notepad++ and compiled it with vs 2022 community.
The first time with a section alignment of 0x1000 the pagesize default aligment and the second time with 0x10000 section aligment and i was comparing the differences.
The vs linker didn't change the file(raw address, raw size) in both files
The only thing changed was the size of image,section aligment,base of code and the virtual address of the sections(in first file the .text section was starting at 0x1000 and in second at 0x10000).
Making a copy of the first file with 0x1000 alignment and manually changed all the fields to try to section align the file to 0x10000 resulted in an invalid pe.
When vs linker does it it does not.

**How to compute the correct virtual addresses based on the 0x10000 section aligment
for the PE sections?**

Answer (score 0):

I have assembled and linked two simple PE files: `t1.asm` with standard section alignment 4 KiB

```
   EUROASM CPU=X64,  TimeStamp=0
t1 PROGRAM Format=PE, Width=64, Entry=Start, IconFile=, \
           FileAlign=512, SectionAlign=0x1000
[.text]
Start: RET
[.data]
  DB "PE"
 ENDPROGRAM
```

and `t2.asm` with alignment increased to 64 KiB:

```
   EUROASM CPU=X64,  TimeStamp=0
t2 PROGRAM Format=PE, Width=64, Entry=Start, IconFile=, \
           FileAlign=512, SectionAlign=0x10000
[.text]
Start: RET
[.data]
  DB "PE"
 ENDPROGRAM
```

assembled and linked them with [EuroAssembler](https://euroassembler.eu/) and compared the executables:

```
R:\>euroasm t1.asm, t2.asm, nowarn=0..999
R:\>dir t?.exe
 Directory of R:\
07.07.2022  09:48             1 026 t1.exe
07.07.2022  09:48             1 026 t2.exe
R:\>fc t1.exe t2.exe
Comparing files t1.exe and T2.EXE
000000AD: 10 00
000000AE: 00 01
000000B1: 10 00
000000B2: 00 01
000000B9: 10 00
000000BA: 00 01
000000BD: 10 00
000000BE: 00 01
000000C9: 10 00
000000CA: 00 01
000000E1: 30 00
000000E2: 00 03
000001A1: 10 00
000001A2: 00 01
000001A5: 10 00
000001A6: 00 01
000001BE: D0 50
000001C9: 10 00
000001CA: 00 01
000001CD: 20 00
000001CE: 00 02
000001E6: D0 50
```

As expected, in `t1.exe` sections **.text** and **.data** start at RVA 0x1000 and 0x2000, while in `t2.exe` they start at 0x10000 and 0x20000.

According to [MS PE32+ specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format#optional-header-image-only) the differences at file offsets `000000AD`..`000000B2` is **SizeOfCode** and **SizeOfInitializedData** in virtual address space rounded up to section alignment.

Differences at `B8`..`BF` are **AddressOfEntryPoint** and **BaseOfCode** (RVA of the first byte in **.text**).

Difference at `C8`..`CB` coresponds with **SectionAlignment** defined in optional header.

Difference at `E0`..`E3` coresponds with **SizeOfImage** rounded up to section alignment.

Following differences concern section headers.
`1A0`..`1A7` describe **VirtualSize** and **VirtualAddress** (RVA) increased from `0x1000` to `0x10000`. Difference at `1BE` concerns section-header **Characteristics**, where the value `0x00D00000` specifies 4 KiB section alignment and `0x00500000` specifies 16 B alignment (64 KiB section alignment isn't available in MS specification, so €ASM reverts to default 16 B, nevertheless this characteristic is relevant in object files only).
The remaining five differeces are analogous for section **.data**.

As you can see, there are many places where you will need to manually change the contents of PE file to keep it valid.